# Firebase.Android emulator: INVALID_APP_CREDENTIALS

Tags: android, firebaseui

My Android app use FirebaseUI.
My app/build.gradle snippet:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0' 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile "com.android.support:design:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0"
```

And when I start my app on device (Android 4.3) I success auth. by Firebase auth.

1. Input phone number
2. Enter SMS code
3. Success auth.

OK. It's work. 
Now I want to do same on emulator:  Nexus One, Android 6.0 (Google API)

But when I try to send phone numbet by Firebase auth. I get error:

[image: Invalid_app_credentials]

Comment: please check google play service in your emulator

Comment: How I check and update google play service on emulator?

Comment: now a day play store come with emulater so check verison of play

Comment: Why Check the play service when phone auth requires a physical device ?

Answer (score 2):

The phone Authentication requires a real or physical device and as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth),

> "Also, note that phone number sign-in requires a physical device and
>   won't work on an emulator."

So you need a physical device for Phone Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Phone Authentication in emulator works but only with testing phone numbers.

> Go to your firebase console -> Authentication -> SIGN-IN Method ->
>   Phone and check the "Phone numbers for testing (optional)" field.

[image]

Comment: what should be the verification code I get error adding test phone number

Comment: What error you are getting. The Test phone number should not be a new number and should not exist in your Authentication database.